# url for posts for a date within a category

Tags: categories, permalinks, date

I am trying to create something like a newsletter.  I'd like to show a set of categories with hyperlinks.  however, I want to restrict that to the specific date.

Clicking on the hyperlink will show the posts within that category and a specific date.

Can I use the a permalink to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add some settings to the permalinks:

Go to: `Settings->Permalinks`

If you want the url like this: `http://example.com/category/2012/12/30/post-name`

Add: `/%category%/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/`

Read more [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks)

Comment: I didn't realize you can reference categories using that format. thanks.

Comment: When I access a url like this:  example.com/category/2012/12/30/  it shows me the posts which match that category and date.  Do you know which php file it calls to display the posts?  Does it use archive.php?  I want to modify the php file

Comment: i think single.php